# What process controls the microphone/camera indicator dots on macOS?

Tags: macos, privacy, control-center

Context for this: my dots got stuck. I had just finished a Discord call, but the dot stayed on all night with Control Center reporting that Discord was using my microphone. I had quit Discord, the app was not running, so there is no way it could still have been using my mic... right?

I know I could restart my computer, but that's a hassle and I'd rather just quit the relevant system process instead. Besides, if there *is* an app hanging onto my mic from beyond the process grave, a reboot wouldn't help me to find *which* app is doing it.

Which program do I kill to reset these dots to make sure Discord (or anyone else) isn't actually using my microphone?

Answer (score 3):

On a hunch, I opened Activity Monitor and found **Control Center**. Quitting that made my status bar go weird for a second, but it quickly returned. And the dot was gone, so I must've guessed correctly.

Loads faster than a restart, and now I know that Discord wasn't actually haunting my computer all night, probably.